# Axon configuration for parallel processing

Tags: axon

I'm trying to run a POC using the axon framework having it share the load for a given saga across multiple application nodes (Server and both client nodes running in docker).  From what I've read thus far the key is to set these properties:

```
axon.eventhandling.processors.mySagaName.mode=tracking
axon.eventhandling.processors.mySagaName.threadCount=2
axon.eventhandling.processors.mySagaName.initialSegmentCount=4
```

Having done so I can see on the Axon Server itself that it's showing multiple segments but if I look on each of my nodes I can see that they are both processing the same records.

Is there something I'm missing in the configuration here?

Comment: Please mind that this configuration is not correct `maybe`: you have split your stream to 4 segments, but you have only 2 threads that can claim only 2 segments. You will have 2 segments unclaimed, and this should be avoided. If you would scale out this app to 2 instances, you would have 4 threads that will claim all your segments which is good. What do you mean by nodes? Nodes of the application?

Comment: Hi Ivan, yes that was my understanding too - so I have two application instances (nodes) actually executing the saga's so with the above I'd expect the two threads running on each box to each claim two different segments so that all 4 segments were being processed across the pair.

Comment: OK, this is fine. Tracking Processors (that you use at the moment) are using a token to mark the position of the event it reads. Is this token persisted in the DB? If it is, make sure that the same instance of DB is used by both instances of your application. If you have H2 (in-memory) DB, then this will not be the case (each app instance will have its own DB).

Comment: Is that not handled by the fact they are both connecting to the same axon server? Do  I need to configure the token store in my application code too?

Comment: Axon Server does not persist token for you. It is a message broker and an event store. You are responsible to store the token in some store. If you use Spring with JPA starter it will automatically configure SQL table as a store (zero config). It is also important that both instances of your app are connected to this token store. sample: https://github.com/idugalic/axon-scale-demo

Comment: THanks for the advice Ivan, I've now got it running as you suggested.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear this!